Got = SyntaxError: node_modules\monaco-editor\esm\vs\base\browser\dom.js: Could not parse entire input - got stuck at position 87 ?:[\w\_])+))?
Currently, when I'm trying to use Monaco Editor to edit my JSON data, it's giving me an issue. The problem is a SyntaxError originating from dom.js file in the monaco-editor package. The error message states: "Could not parse entire input - got stuck at position 87 ?:[\w_])+))?". Here's the list of dependencies I have installed:
react-monaco-editor (version 0.55.0)
monaco-editor-webpack-plugin (version ^7.1.0)
monaco-editor (version 0.48.0)
Below is the file where I have used JsonText.js
/* eslint-disable max-len */

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { getLocalString } from 'pf-core/utilities';
import MonacoEditor from 'react-monaco-editor';
import { Modal, ModalBody } from 'reactstrap';
import cx from 'classnames';
import styles from './styles.module.css';

const VIEW_ICON = (
    <svg width='16' height='16' viewBox='0 0 16 11' fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
        <path d='M7.80013 8.66797C8.63346 8.66797 9.3418 8.3763 9.92513 7.79297C10.5085 7.20964 10.8001 6.5013 10.8001 5.66797C10.8001 4.83464 10.5085 4.1263 9.92513 3.54297C9.3418 2.95964 8.63346 2.66797 7.80013 2.66797C6.9668 2.66797 6.25846 2.95964 5.67513 3.54297C5.0918 4.1263 4.80013 4.83464 4.80013 5.66797C4.80013 6.5013 5.0918 7.20964 5.67513 7.79297C6.25846 8.3763 6.9668 8.66797 7.80013 8.66797ZM7.80013 7.46797C7.30013 7.46797 6.87513 7.29297 6.52513 6.94297C6.17513 6.59297 6.00013 6.16797 6.00013 5.66797C6.00013 5.16797 6.17513 4.74297 6.52513 4.39297C6.87513 4.04297 7.30013 3.86797 7.80013 3.86797C8.30013 3.86797 8.72513 4.04297 9.07513 4.39297C9.42513 4.74297 9.60013 5.16797 9.60013 5.66797C9.60013 6.16797 9.42513 6.59297 9.07513 6.94297C8.72513 7.29297 8.30013 7.46797 7.80013 7.46797ZM7.80013 10.668C6.17791 10.668 4.70013 10.2152 3.3668 9.30964C2.03346 8.40408 1.0668 7.19019 0.466797 5.66797C1.0668 4.14575 2.03346 2.93186 3.3668 2.0263C4.70013 1.12075 6.17791 0.667969 7.80013 0.667969C9.42235 0.667969 10.9001 1.12075 12.2335 2.0263C13.5668 2.93186 14.5335 4.14575 15.1335 5.66797C14.5335 7.19019 13.5668 8.40408 12.2335 9.30964C10.9001 10.2152 9.42235 10.668 7.80013 10.668ZM7.80013 9.33464C9.05569 9.33464 10.2085 9.00408 11.2585 8.34297C12.3085 7.68186 13.1112 6.79019 13.6668 5.66797C13.1112 4.54575 12.3085 3.65408 11.2585 2.99297C10.2085 2.33186 9.05569 2.0013 7.80013 2.0013C6.54458 2.0013 5.3918 2.33186 4.3418 2.99297C3.2918 3.65408 2.48902 4.54575 1.93346 5.66797C2.48902 6.79019 3.2918 7.68186 4.3418 8.34297C5.3918 9.00408 6.54458 9.33464 7.80013 9.33464Z' fill='#484E54' />
    </svg>
);

const JSONText = ({ cell, column }) => {
    const [modal, setModal] = useState();
    const [jsonData, setJsonData] = useState('');
    const [mode, setMode] = useState('light');
    const [modalHeaderText, setModelHeaderText] = useState('');

    const closeModal = () => {
        setMode('light');
        setModal(false);
        setModelHeaderText('');
    };

    const openModalWithJsonData = (cell, column) => {
        if (cell.row.original[column.accessorKey]) {
            setJsonData(cell.row.original[column.accessorKey]);
        } else {
            setJsonData('NO DATA TO DISPLAY');
        }
        setModelHeaderText(column.accessorKey.replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1').replace(/^./, function (str) { return str.toUpperCase(); }));
        setModal(true);
    };

    const toggleMode = () => {
        setMode(mode === 'dark' ? 'light' : 'dark');
    };

    return (
        <>
            <div className={cx(styles['view'], styles['hover-effect'])}>
                {VIEW_ICON}
                <button className={cx(styles['view-button'])} onClick={() => openModalWithJsonData(cell, column)}>{getLocalString('View', 'View')}</button>
            </div>
            <Modal
                isOpen={modal}
                contentClassName={cx(styles['custom-modal'], { [styles['dark-mode']]: mode === 'dark' })}
            >
                <div className={cx(styles['modal-header-section'])}>
                    <div className={cx(styles['modal-header'])}>
                        {modalHeaderText}
                    </div>
                    <div className={cx(styles['modal-header-button'])}>
                        <span>
                            {mode === 'dark' ? `${getLocalString('pf_light_mode', 'Light Mode')}` : `${getLocalString('pf_dark_mode', 'Dark Mode')}`}
                        </span>


                        <label className={styles['switch']}>
                            <input type='checkbox' onChange={toggleMode} checked={mode === 'dark'} />
                            <span className={styles['slider']}/>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <ModalBody className={cx(styles['modal-body'])}>
                    <div className={cx(styles['modal-body-text'])}>
                        <MonacoEditor
                            height='300'
                            language='json'
                            options={
                                {
                                    readOnly: true,
                                    scrollBeyondLastLine: false,
                                    smoothScrolling: true,
                                    readOnlyMessage: {
                                        value: 'Read Only Activated'
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            value={JSON.stringify(jsonData, null, 2)}
                            theme={mode === 'dark' ? 'vs-dark' : 'vs-light'}
                        />
                    </div>
                </ModalBody>
                <div className={cx(styles['buttons-container'])}>
                    <button onClick={closeModal} className={cx(styles['cancel-btn'], { [styles['dark-mode']]: mode === 'dark' })} > {getLocalString('cancel', 'Cancel')} </button>
                    <button disabled={true} className={cx(styles['save-btn'])}> {getLocalString('Save', 'Save')} </button>
                </div>
            </Modal>
        </>
    );
};

JSONText.propTypes = {
    cell: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    column: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default JSONText;

And below is how my config.overrides.js looks like
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const MonacoWebpackPlugin = require('monaco-editor-webpack-plugin');

const appDirectory = fs.realpathSync(process.cwd());
const {
    override,
    addWebpackAlias,
    babelInclude
} = require('customize-cra');
const resolveApp = relativePath => path.resolve(appDirectory, relativePath);
const srcActions = resolveApp('src/actions');
const srcCommon = resolveApp('src/common');
const srcFeatures = resolveApp('src/features');
const srcReducers = resolveApp('src/reducers');
const srcSagas = resolveApp('src/sagas');
const srcServices = resolveApp('src/services');
const srcUIBuilder = resolveApp('src/uibuilder');
const srcUtils = resolveApp('src/utils');
const srcWebapp = resolveApp('src/webapp');
const srcReact = resolveApp('node_modules/react');
const srcReactGridLayout = resolveApp('node_modules/react-grid-layout');

const DEFAULT_VERSION = '3.2';
const PATCH_INDEX = 2;
const packageJson = fs.readFileSync('./package.json');

let appVersion = JSON.parse(packageJson).version || DEFAULT_VERSION;

appVersion = appVersion.split('.');

if (appVersion[PATCH_INDEX] === '0') { appVersion.pop(); }

appVersion = appVersion.join('.');

// function to get the version from package.json
// and insert into the application
const definePackagePlugin = () => config => {
    config.plugins.push(
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'PACKAGE_VERSION': JSON.stringify(appVersion)
        })
    );
    return config;
};

module.exports = override(
    babelInclude([
        path.resolve('src'),
        path.resolve('node_modules/pf-core/uibuilder/DispatchSchduler/index.js'),
        path.resolve('node_modules/pf-core/uibuilder/DispatchSchedulerPro/index.js'),
        path.resolve('node_modules/pf-core/uibuilder/GanttChart/index.js')
    ]),
    addWebpackAlias({
        actions: srcActions,
        common: srcCommon,
        features: srcFeatures,
        reducers: srcReducers,
        sagas: srcSagas,
        services: srcServices,
        uibuilder: srcUIBuilder,
        utils: srcUtils,
        webapp: srcWebapp,
        react: srcReact,
        'react-grid-layout': srcReactGridLayout
    }),
    definePackagePlugin(),
    (config) => {
        config.plugins.push(new MonacoWebpackPlugin({ languages: ['json'] }));
        return config;
    }
);

